# No module named: bert_embedding. Python

Tags: python, module, bert-language-model

So I am using Colab and I have a problem importing bert_embedding...

I use:

```
!pip install bert-embedding
from bert_embedding import BertEmbedding
bert_embedding = BertEmbedding()
```

> Error: No module named bert_embedding

But on the documentation it clearly says that is how I should call it: https://pypi.org/project/bert-embedding/

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Refering to solved issue on github in bert embedding project I would recommend you to install latest gluonnlp package by
`pip install https://github.com/dmlc/gluon-nlp/tarball/master`
https://github.com/imgarylai/bert-embedding/issues/3 - This is that issue I am refering to. This should work for you.

Comment: Hey thanx for the help. I tried to install that on my colab notebook but didn't work.